# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe9' in position 31: ordinal not in range(128) during installing pyramid

Tags: python, pyramid

When I attempt to install pyramid unto a production server ( CentOS 6.4 ), using the following

```
    [~]# env/bin/easy_install pyramid
```

It will show the following stack trace

http://bpaste.net/show/83631/

The steps that I have taken during installation:

1. ssh in as account name ( not root )
2. cd ~
3. mkdir opt
4. cd opt
5. download and install python3.2.3
6. cd ~
7. opt/Python-3.2.3/bin/python3.2 distribute_setup.py
8. opt/Python-3.2.3/bin/python3.2 virtualenv
9. opt/Python-3.2.3/bin/virtualenv --no-site-packages env
10. cd env
11. bin/easy_install pyramid

How should I resolve this?

Comment: No. 8 was meant to be `easy_install virtualenv`?

Comment: yes, and I've resolved it...

Comment: Can you fix this question as well.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this is really simple

in the terminal of the local machine

```
   $ pico .bash_profile
```

at the last line, add in the following:

```
    export LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 
    export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```